# Why the single quotes cannot be removed in this Python code?

Tags: python

I find below code from internet and run it correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import demjson

json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

text = demjson.decode(json)
print  text
```

The result is below:

```
{u'a': 1, u'c': 3, u'b': 2, u'e': 5, u'd': 4}
```

But if I remove the single quotes like this:

```
json = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5};
```

Then error reported:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 6, in <module>
    text = demjson.decode(json)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/demjson.py", line 5701, in decode
    return_stats=(return_stats or write_stats) )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/demjson.py", line 4917, in decode
    raise errors[0]
demjson.JSONDecodeError: a Unicode decoding error occurred
```

Why?

Comment: Flagged as off-topic on *why is this code not working?* category. Learn the basics of Python and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because then it's not JSON. JSON is a ***string*** that looks like JavaScript objects. Making it not a string makes it not JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Well you could do this if you really wanted to:

```
import json  
m = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}  
n = json.dumps(m)  
o = json.loads(n)  
print o['a'], o['b']
```

The main reason why your code won't work is answered by [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38176682/264802):

> Because then it's not **JSON**. JSON is a ***string*** that looks like JavaScript objects. Making it not a string makes it not JSON.